# How to leave only minimal values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good day to all! I need Your help.

I have a DataFrame like:

```
df.sort_values('date')

        name        date    mark
0      Jack       2019-03    4
1      Michael    2019-03    6
2      John       2019-03    9
3      Michael    2019-03    2
4      Jerry      2019-03    4
5      Jack       2019-03    5
6      John       2019-03    3
7      Jerry      2019-03    4
...
857    Jerry      2019-08    5
858    John       2019-08    7
859    Jack       2019-08    4
860    Michael    2019-08    6
860    Michael    2019-08    7
```

I want to leave only minimal values of marks for every person.

For example: if Jack had his minimal grade "**4**" several times, I need to delete other rows where Jack got other grades and leave the ones where he got "**4**". The same logic should apply to others too. Here is an example of a DataFrame I want:

```
df.sort_values('date')

        name        date    mark
0      Jack       2019-03    4
3      Michael    2019-03    6
4      Jerry      2019-03    4
6      John       2019-03    3
7      Jerry      2019-03    4
...
859    Jack       2019-08    4
860    Michael    2019-08    6
```

Could you please advise me on how I should approach this?

Comment: is Jerry supposed to be included twice on 2019-03?

Comment: @rhug123, Yes. There are more columns, that don't matter in a particular example, so one name could be several times in one month.

Comment: Do you only want to delete `mark` with value `4` or any other values?

Comment: Any other values except minimal. For Jack minimal is 4, so I want to leave all rows, where name is Jack and mark is 4, for Michael minimal mark is 6, so I want to leave all rows, where name is Michael and mark is 6, etc. I hope you understand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x[x['mark'] == x['mark'].min()])
```

You can group by names, and apply a filter on each group to match the groups minimum.

Answer (score 2):

I will try with `transform`

```
df_new = df[df['mark']==df.groupby('name')['mark'].transform('min')].copy()
```